# Python - replacing lower case letters

Tags: python, string, replace, lowercase

```
>>> import string
>>> word = "hello."
>>> word2 = word.replace(string.lowercase, '.')
>>> print word2
hello.
```

I just want all the lowercase letters to turn into full stops.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
from re import sub

print sub("[a-z]", '.', "hello.")
```

[`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is looking for the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to replace it with `.`, not looking for each individual letter to replace.

Answer (score 4):

you should use [`string.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
>>> import string
>>> input = 'abcABCaAbBcC'
>>> input.translate(string.maketrans(string.lowercase, '.'*26))
'...ABC.A.B.C'
```

the [`string.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function is a function which helps building a mapping suitable for the `string.translate()` function.

alternatively, you can simply iterate through the string, using a generator:

```
>>> str.join('', ('.' if chr.islower() else chr for chr in input))
'...ABC.A.B.C'
```

Comment: Idiomatically it would be just `''.join('.' if chr.islower() else chr for chr in input)`.

Comment: @agf: yes, but i always felt `''.join(...)` reads backward. so i do always use `str.join('', ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

`string.lowercase` is `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. Your code is replacing every occurence of that entire 26-letter string with a full stop.

Instead, you want to use the `re` module's [`sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re

word = "hello."
word2 = re.sub('[a-z]', '.', word)

print word2
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to replace the string "abc...xyz" instead of replacing every lowercase letter.
You can achieve the wanted result by several ways:

**Regular expressions**

```
from re import sub
sub("[a-z]", '.', "hello.")
```

**Char by char**

```
"".join('.' if l.islower() else l for l in word)
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can use r*eplace* for a mapping like that, but you can do what you want with a simple regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> word = 'hello.'
>>> # the pattern you want to match
>>> ptn = r'[a-z]'
>>> # compile the pattern
>>> pat_obj = re.compile(ptn)
>>> # use the "sub" method to replace text based on a pattern
>>> w2 = pat_obj.sub(".", word)
>>> w2
  '......'
```

Comment: He specifically says _lowercase letters_, so `\w` doesn't fit the bill.